# Qt QRegExp replace all URLs in a string with <a> Anchored URLs

Tags: qt, qregexp

Given a QString that can have an unknown number of URL's in it...

How can I use QRegExp to wrap HTML anchor tags around only the URL portions (with the URL itself as clickable label).

e.g.

```
input: "this is www.cnn.com, that is https://www.mybank.com"

output: "this is <a href="www.cnn.com">www.cnn.com</a>, that is <a href="https://www.mybank.com">https://www.mybank.com</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok. got it.

```
QRegExp regExp("((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\\/\\/)?)(?:[\\-;:&=\\+\\$,\\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9\\.\\-]+|(?:www\\.|[\\-;:&=\\+\\$,\\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9\\.\\-]+)((?:\\/[\\+~%\\/\\.\\w\\-]*)?\\??(?:[\\-\\+=&;%@\\.\\w]*)#?(?:[\\.\\!\\/\\\\\\w]*))?)");

QString result = myOriginalString.replace(regExp, "<a href='\\1'>\\1</a>" );
```

I'll leave the question/answer here for the sake of who may be interested in this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write your regexp for you. However, Qt 4 comes packaged with [a tool that helps a LOT with writing one](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/tools-regexp.html), which you can also compile yourself.

Alternatively, there should be a set of examples and demos included with your Qt installation (On Windows, go to Start -> Qt Examples and Demos). Fire up the examples application and navigate to Tools (second page) -> Regular Expressions. Click Launch and follow the directions.

Use that demo to help you write one out, following guidelines in [the documentation](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qregexp.html). In particular, look into the capturing text, wildcard matching, and character sets sections.